# What puzzle did they change in the Director's cut when compared to the original version?

Tags: version-differences, broken-sword

I've been told that some puzzles have been changed (simplified?) in the Director's cut and also some dialogues have been rewritten.

I'm not talking about the new stuff (i.e. all the Nico's sequences) but the old puzzles that have been remade somehow.

Is there a list of puzzles whose solution is different in the director's cut when compared to the original version?

Answer (score 1):

According to [some comments](http://steamcommunity.com/app/57640/discussions/0/648816742370508572/?insideModal=1), the diference is that in the director's cut, blue circles have been added showing you where to click to advance some puzzles.